# Mysql: Add primay Key in Mysql View?

Tags: mysql

i have created view in mysql database. now i am creating a CRUD Operations in yii using gii application using that view but it is giving an error as primary key in not defined.

How can i define or add primary key in my view as there in no field in my view which is unique.

Comment: You cannot create a primary key on a view.

Comment: http://www.researchgate.net/post/Can_I_set_a_primary_key_in_a_view_in_mysql2

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.
From: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-restrictions.html

> It is not possible to create an index on a view.

Answer (score 0):

## [Primary Key on a View](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9434/primary-key-on-a-view)

> A view is just a stored sub-query.
>
> The idea of a Primary Key is irrelevant.
>
> Views don't have primary keys or indexes
>
> the mysql engine will use the indexes and keys defined on the base table(s).
>
> Please make sure your base table created Primary key.

Answer (score 0):

As per MySql [documentations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-restrictions.html)

- It is not possible to create an index on a view.

Hence you cannot create primary key of view, but you can use primary keys/indexes from table included in view to improve performance of the view.